# Defining statements in finding minimum values in arrays(Java)

Tags: java, arrays

In the first loop, if clause userVals[i] starts at 0 and the comparison will be between the value at index 0 and minVal which is initialized to 0; so, why do I need to have this " minVal = userVals[0]; " statement to set before the for loop.

```
// minVal = userVals[0];
for(i =0; i< userVals.length; i++) {
    if ( userVals[i] < minVal) {
        minVal = userVals[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(minVal);
```

Secondly, let's say minVal = userVals[0]; is a must to have. I think that "i" inside the for loop should start at index 1 since userVals[0] already assigned to minVal. However, in this below case, it doesn't matter where "i" starts at either 0 or 1, it produces the same result.

```
minVal = userVals[0];
for(i =0; i< userVals.length; i++) {
    //for(i =1; i< userVals.length; i++) {
    if ( userVals[i] < minVal) {
        minVal = userVals[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(minVal);
```

Your help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For the first point, you need to set `minVal` to *something* initially. You can pick some marker value then check for it in the loop, use a value like `Integer/MAX_VALUE`, or just use an element of the list. The last way is the cleanest, provided you know the list will contain at least 1 element. If it's empty, `userVals[0]` will cause an error.

For your second point, yes, it looks like you could start the index at 1. I immediately can't see any bugs that would cause.

Comment: Thanks for your help.